# Blockchain (lack of backwards) compatibility in Bitcoincore 0.10.x

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin-core-development

From [Bitcoincore release notes](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/0.10/doc/release-notes.md):

> Because release 0.10.0 makes use of headers-first synchronization and
>   parallel block download (see further), the block files and databases
>   are not backwards-compatible with older versions of Bitcoin Core or
>   other software:
>
> - Blocks will be stored on disk out of order (in the order they are
>     received, really), which makes it incompatible with some tools or
>     other programs. Reindexing using earlier versions will also not work
>     anymore as a result of this.
> - The block index database will now hold headers for which no block is
>     stored on disk, which earlier versions won't support.

How exactly does the new blockchain format effect blockchain parsing projects (of `blkxxxx.dat` files) which likely rely on the old format? Is there a work-around? Are there any other specifics worth mentioning?

Examples of specific projects:

- [John Ratcliff C++ Blockchain parser](https://code.google.com/p/blockchain/)
- [Python code](https://coinlogic.wordpress.com/2014/02/18/the-protocol-1-block/)